# Read files from NAS through smb protocol in a react native application

Tags: react-native, smb

I was trying to develop an application which reads files from network-attached storage through smb protocol. I wasn't able to find anything about it in React's documentation.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do it?

Thanks a lot for reading

Answer (score -1):

There are [a lot of npm packages](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:SMB) providing smb support:

To name a few:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@juangm/samba-client
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@danielhuisman/smb2
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/smb-enumerate-files

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've tried a couple of them and I'd get errors as they expect node modules which are not available in react-native context. Have you tested any of them and found one that does not require node core dependencies? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Recently I developed a react native package for SMB.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-smb
- https://github.com/bodaghialib4/react-native-smb

but it only supports Android.